# python fail to read raw video file

Tags: python, event-based-programming

I am working on event-based video processing. I am new to this now and I have some problems with loading the raw video file into python. Some suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I first tried to read the file directly but got an OSError.

```
OSError: Failed to open camera C:\Users\masiy\Documents\MPhil\Master\raw_videos\recording_2022-02-20_20-50-22 !
```

Then I tried assertion.

````
path = ["Users", "masiy", "Documents", "MPhil", "Master", "raw_videos", "recording_2022-02-20_20-50-22"]
f = 'C:'
for p in path:
    f = os.path.join(f, p)
    print(f)
    assert os.path.exists(f)
assert os.path.isfile(f)```
````

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/Users/masiy/PycharmProjects/mphil_testing/load_automotive_sequence.py", line 34, in <module>assert os.path.exists(f)AssertionErrorC:Users
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried to replace my video with a video downloaded online and the code worked perfectly fine. I am so confused now...

Comment: Where is your downloaded file path?

Comment: My downloaded file is located under C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\file.raw